# Lombok incompatible with IntelliJ 2020.2

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

After the last update to IntelliJ 2020.2 i get the Error:

> Plugin "Lombok" is incompatible (until build 201.SNAPSHOT < IC-202.6397.94).

I've searched for the problem, but it seems that i'm the only one who has the problem with this IntelliJ version.

Comment: https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/840 - always a good idea to look at the plugin's repo.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The solution for me was:

1. Uninstall Lombok Plugin
2. Invalidate Caches & Restart
3. Install Lombok plugin 0.30 EAP
4. Invalidate Caches & Restart

Additional issues mentioned [here](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/840).

Comment: This worked for me as well and should probably be chosen as the correct answer.

Comment: There's an IntelliJ bug and the plugin doesn't work properly at the moment. See here: https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin#unfortunately-the-current-plugin-version-has-a-major-bug-on-new-intellij-20202-and-cant-be-used-normally

Comment: Note: Starting with IntelliJ version 2020.3 lombok plugin will be integrated and included in IntelliJ by default!

Answer (score 8):

I made an update this morning. Everything works. Intellj indicates that it is not compatible, but treats it correctly when updating. The validation of Intellj is incorrect because Lombok delivers the compatibility in the same version.

See: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok

Answer (score 6):

A new version of lombok was released here:
[Lombok](https://github.com/dkowis/lombok-intellij-plugin/releases/tag/2020.2-dkowis)

Just download the .jar file and install the plugin from disk.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems that IntelliJ is not installing automatically new version of lombok plugin.
Let's `uninstall -> restart IDE -> Install` Lombok plugin. (now you will have new version installed)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for 3 plugins, I solved by:
File -> Invalidated caches / restart

Answer (score 1):

The plugin is incompatible with the new version of IntelliJ.
Before validating update to version 2020.2 IntelliJ displays a message of incompatibles plugins and Lombok is one of them:
[image: IntelliJ update warning]

You have the option to go back to IntelliJ version 2020.1 and wait for an update of Lombok

Comment: I've solved this problem by uninstalling and reinstalling lombok. I tried this before but it only worked the secound try.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the last Intellij 2020.2 RC build (which fix this bug) on : https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2020.2+latest+builds

And be careful to also install last lombok intellij plugin (0.30.1).

This issue is detailed on https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/649 and is not entirelly the fault of the plugin (that's why intellij RC must be also installed)

Obviously this solution should be preferred while waiting for a final Intellij 2020.2.1 version.

More detailled information on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-248146 (minimum build version for fix is IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1 RC Build #IC-202.6948.36, built on August 18, 2020)

Answer (score 1):

A new version of the Lombok plugin is bundled with newer versions of IntelliJ. If you have an older version of the plugin already installed and you upgrade IntelliJ, IntelliJ may get stuck in a state that requires manually uninstalling the older plugin.

It appears this is because the older Lombok plugin is incompatible with the newer version of IntelliJ, and the newer plugin is bundled, so it can neither be uninstalled nor upgraded. However, they are not properly treated as two separate plugins, resulting in a plugin incompatible with the installed version of IntelliJ, can't be upgraded, and can't be uninstalled.

To get rid of this conflict:

1. stop IntelliJ
2. delete the plugin directory from the file system; If you have Jetbrains Toolbox, go to IntelliJ IDEA settings, and copy the install location. Remove the Lombok plugin directory `rm -rf lombok-plugin`
3. start IntelliJ
4. feel free to enable the Lombok plugin, and this would be the bundled one now.

Answer (score 0):

Installed latest version(2020.3) of intellij and issue resolved for me.

Answer (score 0):

For intellij, Go to

```
File > Settings > Plugins > Update
```

Answer (score -1):

I basically had to reinstall it twice. This is what I did to resolve the issue:

- Uninstall the plugin
- Invalidate caches and restart
- Install the plugin (issue remained)
- Uninstalled the plugin a second time
- Restart (no invalidate cache this time)
- Install plugin again (issue resolved)

I think someone else mentioned that the plugin does not get installed correctly the first time.